# How do I create a custom struct compatible with Rectangle?

Tags: c#, struct, custom-fields

I want to create a Rectangle struct which has `byte`s for x, y, width and height fields instead of `int`s. It should be compatible with the usual `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle` (casting as `(bytesRectangle)` should be ok). How do I do that?

**Upd:** using this struct helped me save 12 bytes per tile.

Comment: Compatible with Rectangle how exactly?

Comment: I should be able to just cast as BytesRectangle and be ok with that.

Comment: Why do you really need this? Sounds suspiciously like [Premature Optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Comment: I'll try it and see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm interested to know the design choice to implement this struct.  Looking at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle we see there are more than 30 properties and members.  This is a lot to reproduce to save a few bytes.  If your only goal is to save some bytes there might be a better way.   For example if you want to save the data in a smaller space you could define an object and a cast to store it.  Something like this:

```
class SmallRectangle
{
    public byte x { get; set; }
    public byte y { get; set; }

    public SmallRectangle(byte inx, byte iny)
    {
       x = inx;
       y = iny;
    }

    public static explicit operator SmallRectangle(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle big)
    {
        SmallRectangle small = new SmallRectangle((byte)big.x, (byte)big.y);

        return small;
    }

    public WriteToFile(FileStream out)
    {
       //....
    }
}
```

Of course a complete implementation would include testing to make sure there is no data loss on the casting etc.

Based on your comment below:  This is not the direction to go.  If you really need to save memory over XNA while using XNA, then you should make an Small rectangle manager class that does not store them the same way with the same attributes.  But this class is good at creating the XNA ones when you need them.  Don't make the small rectangle class (or the manager) "compatable".

The BEST way to store the data you need in memory is to just store the four BYTES with no overhead.  The best way to store two bytes with no overhead is with the Tuple class.

So I suggest you make a rectangle manager class that internally stores the rectangles as Tuples and then "boxes" and "unboxes" them as needed into Xna objects.

Comment: I really want to save some memory as I'll be using several millions of class instances with rectangle fields in them, but it shouldn't be too hard to rewrite the existing code for that.

Comment: My comment was moved to the end of the answer.

Comment: I think this is called a point. I need all four (x, y, width, height) to work with. Anyway, thanks for the code base, it helped me understand how conversion is made.

Comment: @user1306322 - sure I had a typo, replace "two Bytes" with "four Bytes" -- Tuple is still the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

You'd have to define a conversion to convert your type to the type that the XNA framework expects.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09479473.aspx